# Merge arrays containing the same values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of arrays:

```
var arrays = [
    [1, 2], 
    [7, 5],
    [4, 6], 
    [7, 8], 
    [2, 3],
    [9, 10]
];
```

Arrays that contain at least one equal value must be merged (it doesn't matter if they end up with duplicate values) and the other arrays should remain as they are.
In this example, the result should be:

```
var result = [
    [1, 2, 2, 3],
    [4, 6],
    [7, 5, 7, 8],
    [9, 10]
];
```

Comment: Could specify some more detail, please? What about `[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]`, for example, should that one merge all three arrays into one? Plus, what have you tried so far and what is it that you are stuck with?

Comment: Why? What do these numbers represent?

Comment: This problem is most efficiently solved by the [disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). There are a number of existing javascript implementations.

Comment: Yes, `[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]` should become `[[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]]` or `[[1, 2, 3, 4]]`.
I've tried a lot, a combination of several nested "for" loops. The code turned out pretty ugly and big so I didn't include it in my question.
Basically, in the example above arrays `[1, 2]` and `[2, 3]` would not be merged.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `Array.prototype.reduce`, the array order of this solution is slightly different than the example one(I don't know why the example answer altered the order of original array).

```js
var arrays = [
 [1, 2],
 [7, 5],
 [4, 6],
 [7, 8],
 [2, 3],
 [9, 10]
];

const newArray = arrays.reduce((acc, cur) => {
 const arr = acc.find(a => cur.some(b => a.includes(b)));
 if (arr) {
  arr.push(...cur);
 } else {
  acc.push(cur);
 }
 return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!
Unfortunately, your solution does not work with the following example:
`var arrays = [[1, 2], [7, 5], [4, 6], [7, 8], [6, 7], [2, 3], [9, 10]];`
Compared to the original example, I added the array `[6, 7]`, the result should be `[[1, 2, 2, 3], [7, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 4, 6], [9, 10]] `, but it turns out` [[1, 2, 2, 3], [7, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8], [4, 6], [9, 10]] `.
The array `[4, 6]` results in a separate array, but because of the number 6 it should be merged with `[7, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8]`.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a temporary data set (tempArrays) and running a comparison may help achieve the desired solution.

**Here is the loop construct that can work:**

```
var arrays = [[1, 2], [7, 5], [4, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8], [2, 3], [9, 10]]

// Create a temporary copy of input data
var tempArrays = arrays.slice()

// Remove the first element from temporary set.
tempArrays.shift()

// Check every element in each sub-array of main data set

arrays.forEach(subArray => {
   subArray.forEach(element => {
     tempArrays.forEach(tempSubArray => {         
         if(tempSubArray.includes(element)) {
             // Call the function to merge subArray and tempSubArray
         }         
     })
   })
})
```